# convert string to object for using jQuery.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, select

I create a string:

```
myOption = "{val1:'text1', val2:'text2'...}"
```

I need convert this string into a Object:

```
myOption = {val1:'text1', val2:'text2'...}
```

for using the jquery each function and take a pair value/text in each iteration.

Now in each iteration, it takes one char of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$.parseJSON(myOption);
```

Keep in mind that your JSON string needs to be well-formed, and that means [double-quoting property names and values](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var myOption = '{"val1":"text1", "val2":"text2"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(myOption);
$.each(obj, function(i, val) {
    alert(i + ' ' + val);
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/gr52W/)

Comment: Love it that they added this function :)